# How to paste vim command into vim editor on mac

Tags: mac, vim, vi

I have a bunch of vim commands that I keep in a file because I don't find them easy to remember.

I want to paste them into whatever vim session I'm running.

However, since upgrading to High Sierra, when I paste a vim command into a vim session, it adds the text as if I had asked it to insert the text!

Really, really annoying and I can't figure out how to make it accept the paste as if it were keyboard input.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Well, I have a decent workaround for now - if I type the : then after that the paste works as expected. Even I can remember the : bit :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be able to upgrade to 'high sierra' so I can't confirm yet, but...

This sounds like it has to do with the :set mouse=a command. Type `:set` to view the current setting to the `mouse=` variable. There are a handful of modes for your mouse in vim. I think you want `:set mouse=n`. Type `:help mouse` in vim to see more info. Unfortunately I'm writing this on my phone and can't research/verify further. Hopefully `:help mouse` will give you the info you need to find the proper command to change your mouse behavior.

If `:set mouse=n` fixes your problem then add `set mouse=n` to your ~/.vimrc file. Same command, without the colon.

Comment: the output of :set is:
:set
--- Options ---
  backspace=2         modelines=0         scroll=11           ttyfast             ttymouse=xterm2     window=0
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1

Any Ideas?